# Display a custom price range on WooCommerce Product loops for variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

I am trying display a custom price range for my variable products.
I managed to insert a price range with regular (min and max) prices and sale (min and max) prices.

Here is my code attempt:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_price_format', 10, 2 );
function custom_price_format( $price, $product ) {

    // Main Price
    $regular_priceMin = $product->is_type('variable') ? $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ) : $product->get_regular_price();
    $regular_priceMax = $product->is_type('variable') ? $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) : $product->get_regular_price();
    
    $sale_priceMin = $product->is_type('variable') ? $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true ) : $product->get_sale_price();
    $sale_priceMax = $product->is_type('variable') ? $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'max', true ) : $product->get_sale_price();

    if ( $regular_priceMin !== $sale_priceMin && $product->is_on_sale()) {
        
        $price = '<p class="teste"><del>' . wc_price($regular_priceMin). 'a' . wc_price($regular_priceMax) . '</del></p> <ins>' . wc_price($sale_priceMin) . '</ins>';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

However some sale prices have the same values and the formatting is not correct. 
It creates 3 lines:

- One for the minimum price value,
- another for the letter "a"
- and another for the maximum price value.

How can I organize this correctly?

The tag `<del>` tag is not in the same line.

How can solved this? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try to reword your question as it's unclear and not understandable.

Comment: I update question thx!

Answer (score 0):

Would do you not use standart `$product->get_price_html()` that is available for all type products?

Comment: No! I need this just for type variable products. The others types is ok! The that i use for display max and min price to display in on page shop and category pages in thumbs box of products.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following revisited code that will work everywhere on product loops except on single products for variable products custom price range:

```
// For variable product
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'variable_prices_range_formatted', 100, 2 );
function variable_prices_range_formatted( $price, $product ){
    global $woocommerce_loop;
    // Not on single products
    if ( ( is_product() && isset($woocommerce_loop['name']) && ! empty($woocommerce_loop['name']) ) || ! is_product() )
    {
        // For on sale variable product
        if ( $product->is_on_sale()  )
        {
            $regular_price_min = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true );
            $regular_price_max = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true );

            $active_price_min = $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true );
            $active_price_max = $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true );

            if ( $regular_price_min !== $active_price_min || $regular_price_max !== $active_price_max )
            {
                // Regular price range (for <del> html tag)
                if( $regular_price_min !== $regular_price_max ) {
                    $regular_price_del_html = sprintf( '<del>%s a %s</del>', wc_price($regular_price_min), wc_price($regular_price_max) );
                } else {
                    $regular_price_del_html = sprintf( '<del>%s</del>', wc_price($regular_price_min) );
                }

                // Active price range (for <ins> html tag)
                if( $active_price_min !== $active_price_max ) {
                    $active_price_ins_html = sprintf( '<ins>%s a %s</ins>', wc_price($active_price_min), wc_price($active_price_max) );
                } else {
                    $active_price_ins_html = sprintf( '<ins>%s</ins>', wc_price($active_price_min) );
                }

                $price = sprintf( '<p class="teste">%s %s</p>', $regular_price_del_html, $active_price_ins_html );
            }
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**A variable on sale product price:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help! My code is similar with your. Work too but i have the same problem. See the screen: https://i.imgur.com/XVKqnUL.png Not formated right he use 3 lines. habe <br> for words. Is possible solved this?

Comment: @BarbaraEster This is because there is not enough room (width), so the string breaks in multiple lines… see on my answer, [this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBqVe.png) … My code is clean and without formatting mistakes, based on what you asked. Some CSS might make that better.